# using vsprintf and file operations

Tags: c++, c, file, printf

```
#define printm(X) handleVarArgs X
void writeFile(std::string & s)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fopen("test.txt","w");
    fputs( s.c_str(), fp );
    fclose(fp);
}


void handleVarArgs( char* format, ...)
{
    std::string s;
    va_list args;
    va_start (args, format);
    vsprintf (const_cast<char *>(s.c_str()),format, args);
    va_end (args);
    writeFile(s);
}


const char *  func() { 
    std::string errorLog("Kiev"); 
    return errorLog.c_str();
}

int main()
{

    printm(("My  Name is %s and surname is %s and age is %d",func(),"john",25));
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting segmentation fault if i call writeFile() function. But no segmentation fault when i remove writeFile()
What is the relationship between Files and Var Args?

Comment: No wonder. You should use `FILE *fp = fopen(...)`. That is, assign the return value of `fopen` to `fp`. In the present code, your file pointer `fp` is uninitialised and will likely cause problems in `fputs`.

Comment: Also think about how much space your `std::string s` have, and how can you be sure the `vsprintf` call doesn't go beyond that space ?

Comment: If it is a production code, I would recommend you to capture return values and handle them appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing directly in a `string.c_str()`, simply by removing its constness with a const_cast. This is **bad** and invoke undefined behaviour. So what happens next is simply *undefined* ...

The correct approach for handleVarArgs would be :

- allocate a *bunch* of memory from the heap (with malloc or new[])
- use vs**n**printf to try to write there
- if the return value (say sz) is greater or equal to the allocated size, then free it and realloc a bunch of size `sz+1` and iterate
- then you can safely create a `std::string` from that char array and use it
- do not forger to call free (or delete[]) when finished with the malloc'ed array

Something like :

```
void handleVarArgs( char* format, ...)
{
#define DEF_SZ  256
    int sz = DEF_SZ;
    std::string s;
    while(1) {
        char * buf = new char[sz];
        va_list args;
        va_start (args, format);
        int l = vsnprintf (buf , sz, format, args);
        va_end (args);
        if (l < sz) {
            s = buf;
            writeFile(s);
            delete[] buf;
            return;
        }
        sz = l + 1;
        delete[] buf;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Serge, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `fp` after opening a file?
How does it relate to the value from before opening a file?
The debugger is Your best friend.

It should read: `FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt","w");`
Not mentioning that You should check wether the `fopen` succeeded.